# Studying sequences in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

If a sequence is bounded from above, can we say that it converges and that the superior and inferior limits are equal?

Is it similar if a sequence is bounded from below by some positive constant?

Comment: Consider the sequence $\{(-1)^n\}$.

Comment: You may be thinking of sequences which are bounded above and nondecreasing. There isn't much you can say about convergence with just an upper bound.